# ssh operation timed out while trying to connect from home

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I got server (server X) I'm trying to connect using ssh. But I get 'operation timed out'. It happens only when I'm in home. If I change internet provider it works. Though I can connect to other servers (server Y) using ssh and I can even connect to that server (from Y to X) from another remote server. I've tried already everything and don't know what to to.

No firewalls detected on X server. I also tried passing router over.

What should I to do?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. What does "telnet $IPADDRESS 22" return?

Comment: @Vladimir 
telnet: connect to address $IPADDRESS: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: So it is a network/firewall issue. You would have get a successful connection. You'll need to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

some suggestions on how to debug this:

- make sure you are actually using same ssh port from home and via double-hop or other ISPs
- check dns settings. you local computer may simply have an older IP address caches/hardcoded
- do `traceroute` from those other servers and from another ISP and compare last hops
- check if `fail2ban` is installed on target machine
- if iptables is installed, even if you think its empty, explore `iptables -L`
- restart sshd on target machine (on debian stock configuration, this is safe even when connected via ssh when doing `service ssh restart`)

Comment: If this server is through AWS, also check the security group firewall settings for the instance.